# Check a string for occurrence of multiple values in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm running a check on a retrieved biography string to find out if an artist is still active.

example bio:

```
$bio = 'Band was a psychedelic/progressive rock band';
```

At the moment I have

```
$active = (strpos($bio, 'was an')) ? false : true;
```

But I also want to check for other occurrences. 
Like:

```
$inactives = array('was a', 'was an', 'died', 'were a');
```

Is there a simple way of doing this without the use of a loop? So if the bio string contains any values that are inside the inactives array then return false.

Comment: Somewhat similar; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547478/search-string-with-array-of-values-with-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex approach:

```
if(preg_match('~(was a|was an|died|were a|were an)~', $input)) {
    echo 'not active anymore';
}
```

or simpified:

```
if(preg_match('~(was an?|died|were an?)~', $input)) {
    echo 'not active anymore';
}
```